# Order of commit arguments in git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

In what order does the git command

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
```

Compare the different commits against each other? It seems like if I want to compare the new against the old one I need to do

`git diff [--options] <New_commit> <Old_commit>` in order to see the current diff?

I usually do `git diff [--options] <Old_commit> <New_commit>`

But that seems to be wrong?

When I do for example

```
$ git diff `git rev-list --since="jun 30 2014" --reverse origin/master | head -1` `git rev-list --until="dec 31 2014" origin/master | head -1` --shortstat 

1072 files changed, 389650 insertions(+), 39180 deletions(-)
```

But when I do

```
$ git diff --stat `git rev-list --until="dec 31 2014" origin/master | head -1`
```

I get the printout that:

```
384 files changed, 61255 insertions(+), 20526 deletions(-)
```

Which is not near 300000. So my question is if I should insert the new commit first and the old commit sedond, like:

```
 $ git diff `git rev-list --until="dec 31 2014" origin/master | head -1`..`git rev-list --since="jun 30 2014" --reverse origin/master | head -1`
```

I can't find any documentation about in which order I should insert the commits in order to see the difference between my new and my old commit. Perhaps you can clarify this for me?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
The reason I'm asking is that I want to

1. know how many new lines of code that has been added to a new commit given an old commit, and
2. I want to calculate the number of lines of code in the new commit.

Comment: Kudos for the delta-based explanation :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## TL;DR

In the following `git-diff` syntax,

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

- the first `<commit>` corresponds to the base commit,
- the second `<commit>` corresponds to the commit to compare to the base commit.

Using a mathematically inspired notation,

```
git diff <x> <x+∆x>
```

will show you the difference `∆x`, whereas

```
git diff <x+∆x> <x>
```

will show you the difference `-∆x`.

Note that, because the two commits need not be ordered in any way, either chronologically or topologically, calling them "old" and "new" (as you do) is a bit misleading.

## More details

You can learn a great deal simply by looking up the [`git-diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). Under the *Description* section, you'll find

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
> ```
>
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary `<commit>`.

Granted, that doesn't tell you which commit is which, but, further down, under the *Examples* section, you'll find a couple of illuminating examples:

> ```
> git diff HEAD^ HEAD
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Compare the version before the last commit and the last commit.

and

> ```
> git diff topic...master
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it.

Comment: Thats the thing I don't understand. The intuition tell me I want the git diff <x> <x+∆x> and it tells me that the difference is 389650 insertions(+) wheras when I do $ git diff --stat <x+∆x>  which is the difference between empty project (beginning) and current commit I get 61255 insertions(+) (I.E 61255 lines of code). So git diff <x> <x+∆x> don't work as I want it to work.

Comment: Wheras git diff <x+∆x> <x> gives me that the repo has added 40000 lines of code and deleted around 300000 which is more logic from my point of view so it don't quite work the way I want it.

Answer (score -2):

```
git diff commit_source commit_destination
```

what the `git diff` will show is

- the list of changes that `commit_source` would bring in if you merged it into `commit_destination`

which is not the same as :

- all differences between `commit_source` and `commit_destination`